# Selecting a specific row through select menu - PHP / Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys im working on an admin area for a CMS.

What I'm trying to figure out is how I can have a drop down menu to select a shop from the mysql database, and then use the details of that shop to submit it onto another page for invoicing. I'm not that great at PHP and I've had a look around but couldn't seem to find an answer. Here's the code. Thanks!

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    echo "You aren't logged in, please do so below<br>";
    include('loginform.php');
    exit();
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'aurora');
if (!isset($con)) {
    echo "Connection to Aurora System failed.";
} 
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
echo "$username";

$query = "SELECT area FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $area = $row['area'];
}

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM shops WHERE county = '$area'";
$area_result = mysqli_query($con, $query2);

?>

<form action="time.php" method="POST">
<?php
echo '<br><select name="username">';
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($area_result)){
    echo '<option value="'. $row2['shop_id'].'">' . $row2['shopname'] . ' -  ' .$row2['contactname']. ", "  .$row2['streetaddress'].  '</option>';

}
    $shopid = $row2['shop_id'];
    echo $shopid;
?>
</select><br><input type="submit" value="Register" name="register_button">   <br></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: Add `echo $area` and show us full output of this code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
echo $shopid;
```

It might not fix your problem but you definitely don't want extra strings in the select element

Comment: Yeah that was there just to check if it was working, which it isn't I should of removed that haha

Comment: What happens when you print_r($row2) within that while loop?

Comment: Nothing gets printed. yet in my browser i have entries in my database within the new select menu

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking, but I think this chunk of my own code might be it:

```
<select class="form-control" name="categoria">
                        <option value="">Selecciona una categoría</option>
                        <?php 
                        $q = 'SELECT * FROM categoria';
                        $resultado = mysqli_query($db,$q);
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
                            $selected = "";
                            if(!empty($categoria) && $categoria == $row["categoria"]){
                                $selected = 'selected="selected"';
                            }
                            echo '<option value="'.$row["categoria"].'" '.$selected.'>'.$row["categoria"].'</option>';
                        }
```